# Python encoding problems in xml

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, decode, encode

I have a media player that I would like to send what I'm playing to trakt.tv, everything works fine except for foreign letters in the title/path. The system is running python 2.7.3

```
def getStatus(self,ip,timeout=10.0):
    oPchStatus = PchStatus()
    try:
        oResponse = urlopen("http://" + ip + ":8008/playback?arg0=get_current_vod_info",None,timeout)
        oPchStatus = self.parseResponse(oResponse.readlines()[0])
    return oPchStatus
```

This will return some thing like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theDavidBox>
  <request>
    <arg0>get_current_vod_info</arg0>
    <module>playback</module>
  </request>
  <response>
    <currentStatus>pause</currentStatus>
    <currentTime>3190</currentTime>
    <downloadSpeed>0</downloadSpeed>
    <fullPath>/opt/sybhttpd/localhost.drives/HARD_DISK/Storage/NAS/Videos/FILMS/A.Haunted.House.(2013)/A Haunted House.avi</fullPath>
    <lastPacketTime>0</lastPacketTime>
    <mediatype>OTHERS</mediatype>
    <seekEnable>true</seekEnable>
    <title/>
    <totalTime>4860</totalTime>
  </response>
  <returnValue>0</returnValue>
</theDavidBox>
```

The next step takes the above and assigns each item to a variable.

```
class PchStatus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status=EnumStatus.NOPLAY
        self.fullPath = u""
        self.fileName = u""
        self.currentTime = 0
        self.totalTime = 0
        self.percent = 0
        self.mediaType = ""
        self.currentChapter = 0 # For Blu-ray Disc only
        self.totalChapter = 0 # For Blu-ray Disc only
        self.error = None

class PchRequestor:

    def parseResponse(self, response):
        oPchStatus = PchStatus()
        try:
            response = unescape(response)
            oXml = ElementTree.XML(response)
            if oXml.tag == "theDavidBox": # theDavidBox should be the root
                if oXml.find("returnValue").text == '0' and int(oXml.find("response/totalTime").text) > 90:#Added total time check to avoid scrobble while playing adverts/trailers
                    oPchStatus.totalTime = int(oXml.find("response/totalTime").text)
                    oPchStatus.status = oXml.find("response/currentStatus").text
                    oPchStatus.fullPath = oXml.find("response/fullPath").text
                    oPchStatus.currentTime = int(oXml.find("response/currentTime").text)
```

and so on. Using the above returned xml,

oPchStatus.totalTime would be "4860"
oPchStatus.status would be "pause"
oPchStatus.fullPath would be "/opt/sybhttpd/localhost.drives/HARD_DISK/Storage/NAS/Videos/FILMS/A.Haunted.House.(2013)/A Haunted House.avi"
oPchStatus.currentTime would be "3190"

This, like I said this works well until a foreign letter is in the title. A title like Le.Fabuleux.Destin.d'Amélie.Poulain.(2001).avi will make oPchStatus.fullPath contain the string "/opt/sybhttpd/localhost.drives/HARD_DISK/Storage/NAS/Videos/Le.Fabuleux.Destin.d'Am\xe9lie.Poulain.(2001).avi"

and not

"/opt/sybhttpd/localhost.drives/HARD_DISK/Storage/NAS/Videos/Le.Fabuleux.Destin.d'Amélie.Poulain.(2001).avi"

as i want it to be.

Further on in the script there are routines to scan xml files for the file name and also to create FILENAME.watched so i need to file names to match the actual file name and not replace any letters.

What would be the best way to ensure these types of file names are encoded properly? 
I have tried to provide as much info as possable but if you need more info please just ask.

Comment: The `d&apos;Am\xe9lie` value looks correct *if this is python showing you the element*. If this is what is written to the XML file (so `\xe9`, literally, 4 characters), then something else is wrong.

Comment: What is `oResponse.info()` (in particular `Content-Type` header)? Is there an xml declaration such as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` in the response? Why do you use `response = unescape(response)`?

Comment: Last but not least, is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If the input is a valid xml; it shouldn't be necessary to use `unescape()` at all (hence the "why" question). `"&apos;"` is a [predefined xml entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-predefined-ent) and [`ElementTree` understands it](http://ideone.com/und8nn)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: interesting indeed. Looks like we need more context.

Answer (score 0):

Python is merely keeping your string value printable in ASCII, by showing you the escape code for the `é` character, `\xe9`.

Some notes on your linked source code:

- you should *not* turn the response you want to parse into unicode. *Parse the raw bytes instead*. Parsers expect to decode the contents themselves. In fact, the ElementTree parser will **encode the data again** just to be able to parse it.
- When you have XML in a bytestring, I'd use the `ElementTree.fromstring()` function instead; yes, underneath it uses `ElementTree.XML()` like you do, but `fromstring()` is the [documented API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml).

Otherwise, your example input is working *exactly as it should do*. If I create a XML document from your example with non-ASCII characters in the filepath, I get the following:

```
>>> tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response)
>>> print tree.find("response/fullPath").text
/opt/sybhttpd/localhost.drives/HARD_DISK/Storage/NAS/Videos/Le.Fabuleux.Destin.d'Amélie.Poulain.(2001).avi
>>> tree.find("response/fullPath").text
u"/opt/sybhttpd/localhost.drives/HARD_DISK/Storage/NAS/Videos/Le.Fabuleux.Destin.d'Am\xe9lie.Poulain.(2001).avi"
```

As you can see, the `unicode()` results from `.text` contains a `é` character (Unicode codepoint U+00E9, LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE). When printed as a Python literal, Python makes sure it'll be printable in a ASCII context by giving me the Python escape code for that codepoint, `\xe9`. **This is normal**, nothing is broken.

Comment: The way it is now, oPchStatus.fullPath = oXml.find("response/fullPath").text gets the string with the ASCII codes so when i later want use this string to create a FILENMAE.watched file the names dont match
 path = u'{0}.watched'.format(path)
        if not isfile(path):
            f = open(path, 'w')
            f.close()
path= oPchStatus.fullPath"/opt/sybhttpd/localhost.drives/HARD_DISK/Storage/NAS/Videos/Le.Fabuleux.Destin.d'Amélie.Poulain.(2001).avi" so output file should be "/opt/sybhttpd/localhost.drives/HARD_DISK/Storage/NAS/Videos/Le.Fabuleux.Destin.d'Amélie.Poulain.(2001).avi.watched"

Comment: the response starts with <?xml version="1.0"?> and this python 2.7.3

Comment: You may want to edit your question to add that information. It is not yet clear what `oPchStatus` is, what the value of `oXml.find('response/fullPath').text` is (use `repr(...)` and `type(...)` on that if you can).

Comment: when oPchStatus.fullPath = oXml.find("response/fullPath").text is called it copies everything including the \xe9 but I need it to replace that with é. You can see the whole program here https://github.com/cptjhmiller/pchtrakt/tree/dvp/pchtrakt

Comment: Martijn, thank you very much for your help but im still having issues. with normal files I don't get any issues as for as getting oXml, but with foreign letters the oXml = command fails. I used a try: oXml = ElementTree.fromstring(response)
            except:
    response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="latin-1" ?>' + response) oXml = ElementTree.fromstring(response) This then works but the oXml data is unusable, when I try to split the file name from the path I get, 'Element' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: NO! Do not try and insert your own encoding there. The *default* encoding is UTF8. I have the idea you are blindly hitting at unicode issues here. You are also calling `.split()` on a ElementTree element, not it's contained `.text`..

Comment: If I do nothing then oXml does not get any data and UNKNOWN is returned

Comment: Ignore me, found a typo where fullpath is assigned, I still have to keep the response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="latin-1" ?>' + response) line in tho I believe the xml returned with foreign letters may be corrupt and that fixes it?

Comment: @user1620852: Why do you think the XML returned is mis-encoded? The character `é` is encoded differently in Latin-1 than in UTF-8 (the default for XML). Are there one or two bytes for that character in the raw XML?

Comment: when I open the xml in chrome I get This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 206: Encoding error and without the line above the program fails, with the line the program works but the é is shown now as Ã©

Comment: Then Chrome is wrong, and you should *not* use Latin-1. `u'é'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')` is `Ã©`. You are *misinterpreting* UTF-8 as Latin 1.

Comment: UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding; anything beyond the ASCII characters uses 2 or more bytes *per character*. The U+00E9 codepoint (`é`) is encoded as two bytes, `C3` and `A9`. If you pretend those bytes are Latin-1 *instead*, you get two characters, `Ã` and `©`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1.

Comment: If I change the "Latin-1" to "utf-8" like the encoding should be then the program fails, the only way I can get oXml to get the data is to add that line. This encoding stuff has been driving me mad and I had given up on it but others keep nagging me to fix it so I thought I would give it 1 more go. With out that line the program does not know what is playing so can't do anything else, with the line it can see what is playing and does notify trakt.tv with the correct info but I suspect that later on when it has to create the filename.watched file it will error.

Comment: @user1620852: You *should not change any encoding*. Do not try to decode it. Do not add a header. Leave it to the XML parser.

Comment: Perhaps trakt.tv is broken instead?

Comment: everything this app does with trakt.tv works, ie show what I am watching/watched, it is the local stuff that it is having problems, like I said, it uses the fullpath to get the filename then makes a file in the same path but called FILENAME.watched This file is used when creating a jukebox entry. Like I said, I have to do something or the app will not work.

Comment: @user1620852: I don't understand what doesn't work, but it is *not the XML parsing* that is at fault here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/61zLV9HQ have a look at that link as it shows the log output with and without that line, and I hope shows more clearly what is wrong.

Comment: @user1620852: But *what is the exception* you get? Don't just catch a blanket except and hide what goes wrong. Re-interpreting the data as Latin-1 clearly is *wrong too*.

Comment: There was no exception rasied it just carried on and ended with PCH status = unknown. I will try to run in a terminal to get better idea as to what is happening there. Thanks again Martijn, I really do thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @user1620852: But your code and log output show that the `except:` branch was executed there.

Comment: except ElementTree.ParseError, e:
            oPchStatus.error = e
            oPchStatus.status = EnumStatus.UNKNOWN

Comment: @user1620852: But *why* is there a parser error? What is causing the parser to throw an error? What is the exception there?

Comment: oXml = ElementTree.fromstring(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1282, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1624, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1488, in _raiseerror
    raise err
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 296

Comment: @user1620852: what type is `response`? Is it `unicode` or is it `str`? What *is* the token at line one column 296? Why is that first line so incredibly long?

Comment: sorry for dely, i had to go out. The token at 296 is the é, response is str. I don't know why the line is like that, I just thought it was output like that or the readlines() put it all on 1 line?

Comment: @user1620852: It *could* be that the input XML is all done without newlines. I cannot reproduce the errors you are seeing though; my tests with UTF-8 are working just fine without any parse errors about well-formed tokens.

Comment: Martijn, there an error in the xml feed, this has now been fixed and the code you suggested does now work. I do how ever still have an issue with encodings.for mfile in movie.findall('files/file'):
           mfile.set('watched', 'true')
           bak_name = name[:-4]+'.bak'
           tree.write(bak_name)
           os.rename(bak_name, name)
           txt = name.replace(jukeboxpath, '') + ' has been modified as watched for ' + matchthis
           pchtrakt.logger.info(txt)
       previous = xmlword But the file saved uses &#233; instead of an é, how can I save the file and keep its encoding

Comment: tree.write(bak_name, encoding="utf-8") looks to do the job.